# Disproving that $U_{20}$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $U_{20}$ be the group of invertible elements in $(\mathbb Z_{20}, \cdot)$. Prove that $U_{20}$ is not cyclic, as in it is not generated by one element.

To prove that a group is cyclic I just find some element that generates it. But what is the way of proving that a group is not cyclic? What do we look for?

I thought about this:

> $U_{20} = \{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$, then from a theory if it must be cyclic then it must be isomorphic to some $\mathbb Z_n$.

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, it should be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_8$, since it contains $8$ elements.

Comment: Why $\mathbb Z_8$? We care about the cardinality. Cardinality of $\mathbb Z_8$ is $1$ (since it is generated by one element, $1$), but the cardinality of $U_{20}$ is the number of elements that generate it. I am new to the course. Is there is a misunderstanding that I have of the definitions?

Comment: The only cyclic group of order $n$ is essentially $\mathbb Z_n$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: @TheNotMe "Cardinality od $Z_8$ is NOT 1" it is $8$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $U_{20} = \{1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19\}$ has only eight elements, it is feasible to check this by hand: Computing the powers of $3$ gives that $\langle 3 \rangle = \{1, 3, 7, 9\}$, so if the group is cyclic, it is not generated by any of $1, 3, 7, 9$ (since the groups they generate are subgroups of $\langle 3 \rangle \lneq U_{20}$. Similarly, $\langle 11 \rangle = \{1, 9, 13, 17\}$, and so neither $13$ nor $17$ generate $U_{20}$. The only elements unaccounted for are $11$ and $19$, but both of these have order $2$, so neither of these generate the group either. (In fact, we can conclude from the fact that $U_{20}$ has elements of order $4$ but no element of order $8$ that $(U_{20}, \cdot) \cong (\Bbb Z_4, +) \times (\Bbb Z_2, +)$.)

Comment: How do you quickly know that the groups generated by $1,3,7,9$ are subgroups of $<3>$?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Composition of group elements yields an element of the group. So they have to produce subgroups.

Comment: @TheNotMe Put another way (and restricting to cyclic groups), given any cyclic group $\langle g \rangle$, the elements of the subgroup generated by the arbitrary element $g^m \in \langle g \rangle$ are $e, g^{\pm m}, g^{\pm 2m}, \ldots$.

Answer (score 4):

In a cyclic group $G$ of even order, the set $\{ x \in G : x^2=1 \}$ has exactly $2$ elements, but in $U_{20}$ it has $4$ elements: $1,9,11,19$.

More generally, $U(4m)$ is never cyclic because $(2m\pm1)^2=4m^2\pm 4m+1\equiv 1 \bmod 4m$. And of course $1$ and $m-1$ satisfy $x^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ generates $U_{20}$ we must have a sequence $g^2,g^4,g^8=e$ of three distinct squares. But we have
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x&1&3&7&9&11&13&17&19\\
\hline
x^2&1&9&9&1&1&9&9&1\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
and it is quite clear, that no such sequence exists.

Comment: You should really not say that $g$ is isomorphic to $1$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Right! I understand that. What is the correct wording of it?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Is the current version better?

Comment: The first part is correct, but the second seems to confuse what the operations are in the two groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You mean a confusion between multiplication in the group of inverses versus addition in the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_ 8$? Is there a way to fix my post? I would like it to be helpful rather than confusing.

Comment: Well, what you are really saying is that there must be four distinct squares in the group (you don't really need the first part to see that), and this contradicts your table.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thank you! I think my last edit reflects what you just commented.