# Find all subgroups of $U(20)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to find all subgroups of $(U(20),\cdot)$. I know that
$$U(20)=\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}.$$
I can find some nontrivial subgroups like $\{1,3,7,9\}$ but I want to know if there is some kind of a pattern in finding all these subgroups or do I just have to manually find them all until I'm sure there aren't any more of them?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: $U(20)\cong C_2 \times C_4$. Concretely, every element in $U(20)$ is of the form $\pm 3^n$.

Comment: The subgroups are easily found, using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559565/disproving-that-u-20-is-cyclic?rq=1).

Comment: Look for possible closed subsets of size $2$ and $4$.